VASP Geometry relaxation step does not end
Following are my input files:
INCAR:
SYSTEM  = MONOLAYER-MoTe2
NCORE   = 8

ENCUT   = 500
ALGO    = Fast
IBRION  = 2
ISIF    = 3
NSW     = 1000
POTIM   = 0.5

EDIFF   = 1.0e-04
EDIFFG  = -1.0e-02
ISYM    = 2
LREAL   = .FALSE.


ISMEAR  = 0
SIGMA   = 0.05

PREC    = Accurate
ADDGRID = .TRUE.

NWRITE  = 1
LCHARG  = .FALSE.
LWAVE   = .FALSE.

POSCAR:
Lattice="3.4624380306 0.0 0.0 0.0 6.3778258413 0.0 0.0 0.0 24.1947906566" pbc="T
1.0
        5.2048149109         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         5.2048149109         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         0.0000000000         5.2048149109
   Te   Mo
    2    1
Cartesian
     3.468016925         3.430004900         4.684332420
     1.736797925         2.424706900         0.520481420
     3.468016925         1.774809900         2.505570420

KPOINTS:
MoTe2 kpoints
0
Gamma
8 8 8

Following is one section of the output. Remaining part is similar to this, the simulation keeps on running:
<I'll add this later>
Why does it keep running?
OUTPUT: This is the short version of the output, it is still continuing
vasp.6.4.1 05Apr23 (build Oct 28 2023 16:19:38) complex                         
 POSCAR found type information on POSCAR MoTe
 POSCAR found :  2 types and       3 ions
 scaLAPACK will be used selectively (only on CPU)
 WARNING: type information on POSCAR and POTCAR are incompatible
 POTCAR overwrites the type information in POSCAR
 typ   1 type information:  Mo Te
 WARNING: type information on POSCAR and POTCAR are incompatible
 POTCAR overwrites the type information in POSCAR
 typ   2 type information:  Te Mo
 LDA part: xc-table for Pade appr. of Perdew
 POSCAR found type information on POSCAR MoTe
 POSCAR found :  2 types and       3 ions
 POSCAR, INCAR and KPOINTS ok, starting setup
 FFT: planning ... GRIDC
 FFT: planning ... GRID_SOFT
 FFT: planning ... GRID
 WAVECAR not read
 WARNING: random wavefunctions but no delay for mixing, default for NELMDL
 entering main loop
       N       E                     dE             d eps       ncg     rms          rms(c)
DAV:   1     0.904471517361E+02    0.90447E+02   -0.55848E+03  1600   0.787E+02
DAV:   2    -0.104907564536E+02   -0.10094E+03   -0.91948E+02  2432   0.143E+02
DAV:   3    -0.199316962036E+02   -0.94409E+01   -0.90322E+01  2320   0.482E+01
DAV:   4    -0.202394212337E+02   -0.30773E+00   -0.30503E+00  2136   0.998E+00
DAV:   5    -0.202484089079E+02   -0.89877E-02   -0.89821E-02  2560   0.152E+00    0.118E+01
RMM:   6    -0.191293805966E+02    0.11190E+01   -0.29448E+00  1600   0.822E+00    0.427E+00
RMM:   7    -0.190394142383E+02    0.89966E-01   -0.66759E-01  1600   0.419E+00    0.184E+00
RMM:   8    -0.190273650247E+02    0.12049E-01   -0.14383E-01  1631   0.185E+00    0.374E-01
RMM:   9    -0.190294702033E+02   -0.21052E-02   -0.29395E-02  1668   0.758E-01    0.295E-01
RMM:  10    -0.190298746268E+02   -0.40442E-03   -0.45798E-03  1702   0.315E-01    0.227E-01
RMM:  11    -0.190300331916E+02   -0.15856E-03   -0.19075E-03  1591   0.195E-01    0.601E-02
RMM:  12    -0.190301007819E+02   -0.67590E-04   -0.61266E-04  1366   0.972E-02
   1 F= -.19030101E+02 E0= -.19021067E+02  d E =-.190301E+02
 curvature:   0.00 expect dE= 0.000E+00 dE for cont linesearch  0.000E+00
 trial: gam= 0.00000 g(F)=  0.112E+00 g(S)=  0.155E+01 ort = 0.000E+00 (trialstep = 0.100E+01)
 search vector abs. value=  0.166E+01
 bond charge predicted
       N       E                     dE             d eps       ncg     rms          rms(c)
DAV:   1    -0.227837413203E+02   -0.37537E+01   -0.13438E+02  1744   0.724E+01    0.201E+01
RMM:   2    -0.188834972614E+02    0.39002E+01   -0.56995E+00  1600   0.130E+01    0.680E+00
RMM:   3    -0.184372419841E+02    0.44626E+00   -0.19530E+00  1611   0.714E+00    0.138E+00
RMM:   4    -0.183857418327E+02    0.51500E-01   -0.22392E-01  1605   0.290E+00    0.129E+00
RMM:   5    -0.183895974960E+02   -0.38557E-02   -0.83289E-02  1650   0.142E+00    0.106E+00
RMM:   6    -0.183883033496E+02    0.12941E-02   -0.17650E-02  1610   0.894E-01    0.282E-01
RMM:   7    -0.183876925054E+02    0.61084E-03   -0.12299E-02  1610   0.518E-01    0.156E-01
RMM:   8    -0.183879076639E+02   -0.21516E-03   -0.20329E-03  1664   0.234E-01    0.335E-01
RMM:   9    -0.183879444426E+02   -0.36779E-04   -0.28474E-04  1247   0.964E-02
   2 F= -.18387944E+02 E0= -.18384504E+02  d E =0.642156E+00
 trial-energy change:    0.642156  1 .order    1.008730   -1.661980    3.679440
 step:   0.4108(harm=  0.3111)  dis= 0.02134  next Energy=   -19.396902 (dE=-0.367E+00)
 bond charge predicted
       N       E                     dE             d eps       ncg     rms          rms(c)
DAV:   1    -0.210876285723E+02   -0.26997E+01   -0.44542E+01  1832   0.398E+01    0.108E+01
RMM:   2    -0.195357458270E+02    0.15519E+01   -0.25423E+00  1600   0.938E+00    0.436E+00
RMM:   3    -0.194343135143E+02    0.10143E+00   -0.71204E-01  1610   0.418E+00    0.203E+00
RMM:   4    -0.194173025656E+02    0.17011E-01   -0.10339E-01  1605   0.166E+00    0.574E-01


+1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future!!! However, the output needs to be printed in a code block, and not in a screenshot image.

Welcome!
From looking at the output:

WARNING: type information on POSCAR and POTCAR are incompatible

it looks like you defined types in POSCAR in a different order than POTCAR. So the structure you're trying to relax isn't close to the starting structure. It probably will never relax.
Double check the order of the data in POTCAR vs POSCAR. If they are wrong, swap them and let us know if this fixes it!

I swapped the 2, still got the error. However, I checked and found that my structure had somehow changed from hexagonal to cubic when converting from vesta to POSCAR format. Also, I reduced the NSW to 800, not sure if this had any effect, but my calculation converged.

If you still got the error, something else must be wrong too... make sure you are using the correct POTCAR datasets and they are in the correct order. Either way, glad you got it sorted out :)
